# Project command, project start --dry-run vs project validate

Tags: apex, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

I'm trying to reach the reasons to use project validate instead of project start --dry-run. Due to, when using dry-run in project start, seems to have the same result of project validate.

1. [Project start Command](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_deploy_start_unified): Deploy metadata to an org from your local project. Flag: --dry-run:  Validate deploy and run Apex tests but don’t save to the org.
2. [Project validate Command](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_project_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_project_deploy_validate_unified): Validate a metadata deployment without actually executing it.

In both commands, after the end of the unit tests validation, an Id is available to use quick deploy. So that, what is the main difference in the result of the execution in deployment API, between both commands?

Comment: I am wondering the same thing, haven't been able to find anything specifying the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run validate with --test-level set to NoTestRun, it will return an error

> Expected --test-level=NoTestRun to be one of: RunAllTestsInOrg,
> RunLocalTests, RunSpecifiedTests

You can however do a dry run deployment while running no tests.  It means the components can be validated without having to run tests (good for components which can be deployed without running tests).

This will fail:

```
sf project deploy validate --test-level NoTestRun --metadata LightningComponentBundle:MyComponent
```

This will validate the components:

```
sf project deploy start --dry-run  --test-level NoTestRun --metadata LightningComponentBundle:MyComponent
```

**When to use validate**

It seems you cannot do a quick deploy after doing a dry run deployment - it doesn't count it as a validation.  So if you want to use the quick command you need to use `validate`